# java - Reading and writing text in spezific locations inside a .txt file

Tags: java, io, nio

I am very confused by the amount of different read and write methods in Java and couldn't find one that fits my needs.

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
CharName{
    Sheet{
        Vitality{
            Short=LP,Name=Life,Base=1000,Equip=0,Buff=0;
            Short=LPR,Name=Life regen per sec,Base=50,Equip=0,Buff=0;
        }
        Magic{
            Short=MP,Name=Mana,Base=100,Equip=0,Buff=0;
            Short=MPR,Name=Mana regen per sec,Base=5,Equip=0,Buff=0;
        }
    }
}
```

It's actually a lot bigger, but that much is sufficient to show what I mean.

I want to make a function that basically looks something like `getInfoFromCharFile(sectionName, categoryName, rowNum, tagName)`.

Example: `getInfoFromCharFile(Sheet, Vitality, 2, Name)` so that it gives me *50*) and also the same with writing `saveInfoToCharFile(sectionName, categoryName, rowNum, tagName, newValue)`

On top of that comes that I'm trying to make it that when one of those files gets read, I have an easy method of 'loading it in' (reading everything systematically) - so something that goes like "find *sheet*; find *Vitality*; get everything in between the next { and }; split at **;**;.; find *Magic*; get everything in between the next { and };. And so on and so forth.
I have an idea how to do the spiting and processing, but how can I get it to 'load' everything in between the braces?

Note: I did read, watch and Google a lot about this, but couldn't find anything that gave me an idea on how to solve my problem. I'm sitting on this problem for weeks now! I used to just use properties, but that got really ugly really fast.

I would show you the code to 'load' in that solution, but the last time I had to edit it, it literally took me hours to understand it again - so yeah, not very good code I guess, that's why I want to replace it like that.

Comment: Never; ever; do inline replacement in text files. This is a surefire recipe for data loss. That said, as mentioned, consider using a standard format. Plenty of them exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to to this:

1. The hard way:
   You insist to use your custom format. In that case, you will probably have to use regular expressions to read your files, you will have to be prepared to handle malformed input, etc.
   You can use Matcher or Scanner to do the matching. If you feel adventurous, you can do state-based parsing, by reading the chars one by one.
   I actually did [something like that](https://github.com/TheOnlySilverClaw/JavaObjectNotation) a while ago and maybe you can take inspiration from the source...or even use it, last time I checked, it worked. (especially the [JONReader](https://github.com/TheOnlySilverClaw/JavaObjectNotation/blob/master/jon/io/JONReader.java) could be useful.
2. The easy way:
   Use a standard format like XML, JSON (your format is already quite close to that anyway!), or even some CSV stuff. There are a lot of solid parsers for those out there, and it might become as easy as "charname.getMagic()", without worrying for the details.

If you decide to use JSON, what would seem the most fitting thing for your approach, I suggest having a look at [minimal-json](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), depending on how you want to work with it.